# VBS scripting to create a hotlink to external website in Excel

Tags: excel, url, vbscript, vba

We have a routine that creates a file to be run using VisualBasic that then creates an Excel spreadsheet. The method is relatively simplistic, but I have run into an issue trying to create a clickable URL to an external website. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
xlApp.Cells(14,1).Value="3. Here is some valid sample text:"
xlApp.Cells(14,1).WrapText=True
xlApp.Cells(14,1).Font.FontStyle="Plain"
xlApp.Cells(14,1).HorizontalAlignment=-4131
xlApp.Cells(14,1).IndentLevel = 3
```

***This is the section that doesn't work
    xlApp.Cells(15,1).Select
    xlApp.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor=Selection, Address:= _
        "http://www.testedu.edu/", TextToDisplay="www.testedu.edu"

---

```
xlApp.Cells(16,1).WrapText=True
xlApp.Cells(16,1).Font.FontStyle="Plain"
xlApp.Cells(16,1).HorizontalAlignment=-4131
xlApp.Cells(16,1).IndentLevel = 3
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved=True
```

I have tried a variety of options to get an active URL created, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. I have tried using the =HYPERLINK syntax, but wasn't successful, have tried all kinds of other stuff, but can't find the key. I'm hoping there's someone that can identify the issue and set me straight.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Your code to add the hyperlink is using "=" when it should use ":=".  Try this.

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="http://www.testedu.edu/", TextToDisplay:="www.testedu.edu"
```

Steve